# How do you create ad-hoc users on SQL Server 2008 

Tags: sql-server-2008

I use SQL Server Management Studio to manage my SQL Server. I need to add a `genericReadOnly` and `genericReadWrite` to use when accessing it from automated vba code in Excel. The file that contains this code will be distributed to a number of people, more than I want to individually add to the server.

I've tried adding this generic user account, but get told

> *genericReadOnly is not a valid login or you do not have permissions.*

The server admin believes that a username has to exist in Active Directory.

Is this standard, or is it a sitting that can be changed, if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using mixed authentication on your SQL Server, you can create a SQL Server login (via the security\logins tree on SSMS object explorer) and then a user on your database.

If you are using windows authentication only, then yes, you need an Windows login account mapped to that user.

To change the authentication mode... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx